# RegEx for matching IPs in specific format

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have this line:

```
OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60
```

How can I only get src = (ipaddress) and just get the ipaddress?

#### Attempt:

```
SRC=(.+)(\d+)(.+?(?=DST))
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code you've written so far.

Comment: Or another regex: [`/SRC = ((?:\d{1,3}\.?\b){4})/g`](https://regex101.com/r/EpgIyV/1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex and extract IP from group1.

```
SRC\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})
```

Notice this regex also relaxes the amount of whitespace present between `SRC`, `=` and IP by using `\s*` in the regex and enabling case insensitive match will help matching `src` too.

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lIaRKs/1/)**

JS Code demo,

```js
const s = 'OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.85 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.86 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60'
const reg = /SRC\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})/ig

while((m = reg.exec(s))) {
    console.log(m[1])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a positive lookbehind regex, like this:

`(?<=SRC = )\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}`

regex101 example: https://regex101.com/r/cuAUm3/1/

javascript code:

```js
const regex = /(?<=SRC = )\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}/gm;
const str = `OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60`;

console.log(str.match(regex));
```

RESULT:

```
Array(3)
0: "222.187.221.84"
1: "222.187.221.84"
2: "222.187.221.84"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should get you the ip

```js
var ipReg = /SRC = (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/;

var str = 'br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60';

var ip = str.match(ipReg)[1];

console.log(ip)
```

Answer (score 0):

As other answers have suggested: You could use something like:

```
var regex= /SRC = (\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/g;
```

OR:

```
var regex= /SRC\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/g;
```

Capturing in Parenthesis the Group you are trying to match:

```
(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})
```

Then you can keep on executing the Regular Expression for all the matches in your String.

```js
var txt= "OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60 OUT = br0 SRC = 222.187.221.84 DST = 192.168.1.20 LEN = 60";
var regex= /SRC\s*=\s*(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})/g;

var match = regex.exec(txt);
while (match != null) {
    console.log(match[1]);
    match = regex.exec(txt);
}
```